# Problem in show precision of print python

Tags: python

When i use `%f` in print it dosent work properly like the format type.

my code is:

```
a=13
print('dfdsfds %2f'%a +"  {:.2f}".format(a))
```

the answer is:

```
dfdsfds 13.000000  13.00
```

and the `%numf` just shows 6 precision and it doesn't care what is the num. why this happens?

Comment: Did you mean `%.2f`? See [PyFormat](https://pyformat.info/#number) for comparison between old and new string formatting specifiers

Comment: Use `%0.2f` instead of  `%2f`

Comment: yes but i dont use dot case it raise error.

Comment: Highly related: [limiting floats to two decimal points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work properly. You just wrote to a different format Strings. If you change it to this:

```
a=13
print('dfdsfds %.2f' % a + "  {:.2f}".format(a))
```

You will get the output:

```
dfdsfds 13.00  13.00
```